# MVC5 Area not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have two Areas in my MVC 5 app that are not working properly.

When I use the following Link `http://localhost:45970/Admin/Admin` the app loads the proper index.cshtml whicxh is located at `/Areas/Admin/Views/Admin/Index.cshtml` however when I try to load `http://localhost:45970/Admin` it tries to load the Index.cshtml file from `/Views/Admin/Index.cshtml`.

All the search results say I am doing the correct thing. I have even loaded a sample API project to look at the help area in it to make sure I was doing things correctly.

**Here is my RouteConfig.cs file**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace BlocqueStore_Web
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "BlocqueStore_Web.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the Application_Start() section of my Global.asax.cs file**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

**And finally my AdminAreaRegistration.cs file**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace BlocqueStore_Web.Areas.Admin
{
    public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
       public override string AreaName 
       {
          get 
          {
             return "Admin";
          }
       }

       public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
       {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "BlocqueStore_Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

So, what am I missing?

Comment: Which view do you want to load when the url is `http://localhost:45970/Admin`?

Comment: by default it should load /Areas/Admin/Views/Admin/Index.cshtml

Comment: realized that as soon as I het the return key - corrected comment above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't set the default controller when registering `Admin` area. Set the controller to `Admin` and action to `Index` in the `defaults` parameter of `context.MapRoute` method

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Index", controller = "Admin", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "BlocqueStore_Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

Comment: You sir are a **GENIUS**. Worked like a charm, Thank you.

Comment: Added a new post that is related to this one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988376/mac5-area-not-behaving-properly

Comment: I got stuck in a completely different situation!
Two folder was created with exactly the same name of Area and Controller!
Like in this case Folder Name: Admin Sub-Folder Name: Admin!