# MVC5 Area not behaving properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-areas

This post is directly related to: [MVC5 Area not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987453/mvc5-area-not-working)

That post fixed the index.cshtml issue, however it did not resolve each view for that controller. For example:

`http://localhost:45970/Setup/Start` gives the error that the resource cannot be found (basically a 404).

However `http://localhost:45970/Setup/Setup/Start` brings up the correct page.

So what needs to be reconfigured so that **ALL** views for that controller in the Setup Area will open properly?

**Edit 1**

**Code from SetupAreaRegistration.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace BlocqueStore_Web.Areas.Setup
{
    public class SetupAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Setup";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                name: "Setup_default",
                url: "Setup/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index", controller = "Setup", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "BlocqueStore_Web.Areas.Setup.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the area named `Setup` or `Admin`?

Comment: either actually, I have two areas, Admin and Setup. I need both to actually behave properly. Meaning when I goto /Admin/Employees the site pulls up /Areas/Admin/Views/Employees. Likewise with setup /Setup/AddSiteLogin needs to pull up /Areas/Setup/Views/AddSiteLogin page. The same goes for any view located in those two Areas respectively.

Comment: Can you add the code of SetupAreaRegistration.cs ?

Comment: If you have an Area named Setup, then `http://localhost:45970/Setup/Start` will point to the controller named `Start` under `Setup`. I'd guess you don't have StartController under Setup Area.

Comment: {Lightbulb} {FacePalm} - I just realized that. No I do not have a Start controller, just have the setup controller. Is there any way to make all the views in the setup controller of that area show up as http://{host}/Setup/{view}, Same with the Admin Area? Its controller is Admin

Comment: If you want `http://{host}/Setup/‌​{view}`, you don't even need a Setup Area. You only need SetupController without Area. Same thing with Admin.

Comment: OK,... what I was trying to avoid, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an Area named `Setup` with the above route configuration, opening `http://localhost:45970/Setup/Start` will execute `StartController` under `Setup` Area. You got 404 error because you don't have `StartController` under `Setup` Area, but you can open `http://localhost:45970/Setup/Setup/Start` successfully because you have `SetupController` and `Start` action method under `Setup` Area.

Based on your comment, you want the following url patterns

```
http://{host}/Setup/‌​{view}
http://{host}/Admin/‌​{view}
```

You can accomplish that without using any Area. You only need `AdminController` and `SetupController` using the default route.